# angular custom component and angular routing not working

Tags: angular, routes, angular8

file hierarchy:

[image]

I can access /test but it returns blank page.

test.component.html

```
<h1>Hello its working now </h1>
<p>test works!</p>
```

test.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-test',
  templateUrl: './test.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./test.component.scss']
})
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

app-routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { TestComponent } from './test/test.component'; 

const routes: Routes = [
  { 
   path: 'test', 
   component: TestComponent 
  },


]; 

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
export const routingComponents =[HomeComponent, TestComponent]
```

I'm beginner in angular

Comment: have you added `router-outlet` in app.component.html file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your ***app-routing.module.ts*** everything seems ok. Now, You have to import that module in your ***app.module.ts***

app-routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { TestComponent } from './test/test.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'test', component: TestComponent },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

So in app.module.ts you need to import ***AppRoutingModule***. In `imports: []` array simply add ***AppRoutingModule***

app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { TestComponent } from './test/test.component';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, FormsModule, AppRoutingModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, TestComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Now you can use `<router-outlet>`. So when user navigate to '/test' below  will render your TestComponent.

**Note**: if you are using *grid-layout*  will take 1 column/row. It will be rendered with your TestComponent.

app.component.html

```
<h1> Working example </h1>
<a [routerLink]="['/test']" routerLinkActive="active"> Test </a>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Comment: working example [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gvn4ux?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: Okay I missing <router-outlet></router-outlet> from app.component.html thats why i font that issues.

Comment: Yes, and including that in app.component :) Mark an answer please if it helped.